# Html File path to subfolder

Tags: html, atom-editor

Using atom code editor I have a folder "login". I also have a subfolder "register".

I can access the login.html in my browser from a button on the index.html. However, once I am on the login.html, I can not get to register.html

Once I try to access the register page from a button on my login page in my browser I am given the following:

```
/myproject/Login/Login/Register/register.html
```

If I remove one of the /login I am given the page I want. Not sure why my file path is not directly working from the button on my login.html

```
<a class="txt2" href="Login/Register/register.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change to

```
<a class="txt2" href="../Login/Register/register.html">
```